# C++ - Read data from Buffer

Tags: c++

How can i read data from my memory buffer?

```
const char *buf
```

and then print it out like this

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, "Buf: " + buf, " ", MB_OK);
```

Comment: If you are using C++, please use a string class. std::string or whatever your favorite library uses.

Comment: It depends what you mean with _read_. From where? To where?

Comment: You could try `("Buf: " + std::string(buf, n)).c_str()`... you need to work out how many bytes - `n` - are meaningful in the buffer.  And I'm just guessing that this `MessageBoxA` function will accept a `const char*` argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string str = "Buf: ";
str += buf;    // I assume buf is a null terminated string
MessageBoxA(NULL, str.c_str(), " ", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply `+` on string literals and/or `char*`. One of the operands has to be a `std::string` to be able to take advantage of `std::string`'s `operator+` overload.

If your `buf` is a char array, then something like this could work:

```
std::string("Buf: ") + buf
```

This requires that `buf` is **null-terminated**.

If `buf` isn't null-terminated however, Tony D's solution should work.